# Wrong video size when using python-vlc with Tkinter on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tkinter, vlc, python-vlc

I am developing a multi-platform application that manipulates VLC through python-vlc and makes it draw in a Tkinter window.
I am using the following simplified code (inspired from the [`tkvlc.py` example from python-vlc](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/38a90baf1d6c1e9a6131433ec3819766f308612c/examples/tkvlc.py)):

```py
import os
import platform
import sys
import tkinter
from ctypes import c_void_p, cdll
from threading import Thread

import vlc

system = platform.system()

if system == "Darwin":
    # find the accurate Tk lib for Mac
    libtk = "libtk%s.dylib" % (tkinter.TkVersion,)
    if "TK_LIBRARY_PATH" in os.environ:
        libtk = os.path.join(os.environ["TK_LIBRARY_PATH"], libtk)
    else:
        prefix = getattr(sys, "base_prefix", sys.prefix)
        libtk = os.path.join(prefix, "lib", libtk)
    dylib = cdll.LoadLibrary(libtk)
    _GetNSView = dylib.TkMacOSXGetRootControl
    _GetNSView.restype = c_void_p
    _GetNSView.argtypes = (c_void_p,)
    del dylib


class Window(tkinter.Tk):
    def register(self, player):
        id = self.winfo_id()
        print(id)

        if system == "Darwin":
            player.set_nsobject(_GetNSView(id))
        elif system == "Linux":
            player.set_xwindow(id)
        elif system == "Windows":
            player.set_hwnd(id)


def play(instance, player, path):
    media = instance.media_new_path(path)
    player.set_media(media)
    player.play()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    instance = vlc.Instance()
    player = instance.media_player_new()
    window = Window()
    window.register(player)
    thread = Thread(target=play, args=(instance, player, sys.argv[1]))
    thread.start()
    window.mainloop()
```

On MacOS, the size of the video is not adapted to the size of the window.
If the video is to large for the window, it is cropped, if it is too small, it stands in the left bottom corner and is surrounded by black.
The size of the video is updated only when the window is resized.
[Here](https://youtu.be/o8jT3zTzhlU) is a video capture of the problem.
This does not occur on Linux or on Window.

The same problem occurs with the [`tkvlc.py` example from python-vlc](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/38a90baf1d6c1e9a6131433ec3819766f308612c/examples/tkvlc.py)) if the call to the `OnResize` method is blocked line 471 (the method resizes the window to have the size ratio of the video).

What should I do to force VLC to resize the video to fit the window automatically, as it does by default on other OSes?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed that error by understanding the code in tkvlc.py code in the examples https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/examples/tkvlc.py

The function that resizes the video in mac os if it's wrong is this one in tkvlc.py:

```py
def _wiggle(self, d=4):
  # wiggle the video to fill the window on macOS
  if not self._isFull:
    v = self.videoPanel
    g, w, h, x, y = _geometry5(v)
    w = int(w) + d
    # x = int(x) - d
    # h = int(h) + d
    if _geometry(v, w, h, x, y) != g:
      self.after_idle(_geometry, v, g)
      if d > 1:  # repeat a few times
        self.after(100, self._wiggle, d - 1)
```